# Uploading .doc and .docx in compatibility mode - all images gone

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-api

When uploading (and converting) either .doc or .docx in compatibility mode files to Google Drive, all the images inside the document disappear.
Tested via browser and via documents list API.
This seems a rather extreme change of behaviour (as far as I can tell as working until some days ago) and I can't find any patch notes indicating any change. In fact, the ones I found said [this](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.ca/2012/09/scheduled-release-track-features-update_26.html):

Note: 
The ability to import Office files of any format to Google Docs is still supported and will remain unchanged.

Is this behaviour intentional?